# Integration of html into joomla

Tags: html, joomla, joomla-template

I have html/css of a website and i want to integrate that website into joomla 2.5 (Template)

Then how to integrate template in joomla plz let me know?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/16538

Or directly this service - http://www.htmltojoomla.com/

And than you could try this to automatically migrate from 1.5 to 2.5 - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658

Comment: @shershen:-Great work man,i want to learn joomla please provide help so i shall be highly thankfull.....

Answer (score 0):

There are a great number of tutorials available for helping with template creation for Joomla.  Here is a [Joomla Link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2545347) - good links within that.  It's for 1.6 which was a stepping stone to 1.7, which is now 2.5.

Here is [another tutorial](http://www.lbsaud.com.np/joomla-template-tutorial/)

You could also read up on [this tutorial](http://www.barryflood.com/blog/34-blog/102-tutorial-creating-a-joomla-25-compatible-template.html)

After reading up on those you should have at least a good basic understanding how of the joomla template is made up and built in 1.6/1.7/2.5.  I hope that helps!